# Load data from cookie event

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Please give peace of advice. I have login form. Login and password textboxes, and button 'enter'. Button disabled if textboxes are empty. So I've made client side event that makes button enable. Event TextChaged for both textboxes. But after entering to application users login and password wrote to cookies. When I entering the next time, I past the login name into the first box, password appears automatically. And 'enter' button still disabled. Does exist some event that occurs after cookies was paste?
ps: used devexpress textboxes

Comment: is client-side TextChanged event is raised when restoring values from cookies for both DevExpress ASPxTextBox and normal input?

Answer (score 0):

When you enter Login details second time, your textchange event should ideally have fired!  and 'Enter' button should have been enabled. Are you sure its all working fine?

Alternatively, here is what you can do:

onblur event of the textbox, check the length of both the text boxes (Login & Password). If length is greater than zero for both textboxes, enable the Enter Button.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "onblur" probably that what I need. Will try it